# Windows Communication Foundation with x509 and Compact Framework 3.5 Max Keylength

Tags: .net, wcf, frameworks, x509, makecert

I am using Windows Communication Foundation with x509 message layer security to communicate with a windows compact framework 3.5 device.

I am using makecert to create the certificates.

Does anyone know what is the largest size of key length I can use in this situation? currently using 1024 but would like to move up 2048.

I know the default keylength for makecert is 1024 but cant find anymore information or if there is a limit on what the compact framework can handle...

Answer (score 0):

The RSA implementation used by the .Net framework, RSACryptoServiceProvider, actually uses the underlying Windows CryptoAPI implementation. Most modern Microsoft OSes support 384 to 16384 bit key sizes (see [RSACryptoServiceProvider.KeySize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.keysize%28v=vs.90%29)). You can call [RSACryptoServiceProvider.LegalKeySizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes%28v=vs.90%29) to see the accepted values on the target platform, too.